# Why browser doesn't fire change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
<input type="text" id="pies" value="" />
```

and

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#pies').on('change', function() { alert('cham'); });
    $('#pies').focus();
    $('#pies').val('kooooo');
    $('#pies').blur();
});
```

Why browser doesn't fire change event? How can I make that browser will fire change event. I don't want to trigger "change" manually, because if I will trigger change, in some cases trigger change will be triggered twice. This is only example.

Comment: You'll have to call it manually.

Comment: Is it not firing when you change it manually, or when you're forcing it to change like the code you've posted?

Answer (score 1):

Call the change using :

```
$('#pies').change();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it manually

```
$('#pies').change();
```

[As docs says](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to  elements,  boxes and  elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.

In auto complete case try to do `$("#pies").trigger("autocompleteselect");`

Comment: Because I'm using jquery autocomplete and event "change" is not triggered in some cases, but these cases are hardly to exclude. If I trigger change in "change: function()" in autocomplete, change will be triggered twice in other cases.

Comment: Thanks, but I checked 'autocompleteselect' is triggered in all cases. 'change' is not triggered when user click on an input field and select an option without pressing keys on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Better use `keypress` instead of `change`